# Unable to initialise using @FindBy in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am trying to perform basic selenium operations using page object pattern. However, when I run the test, I see browser being opened along with given url, but fails the test by complaining it couldn't initialise the declared web element. Can some one please help me to understand what I'm missing here. Below are my base class, page object class and test class.

**BasePage**

```
public class Basepage {

public static WebDriver driver;

public Basepage(){}

public Basepage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

public void OpenBrowser(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
"C:\\SeleniumWork\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Page object class

```
public class SecurityMainPage extends Basepage{

public SecurityMainPage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

@FindBy( xpath = "//a[text()='What We Do']")
WebElement dropdown;

public void selectOption(String option){
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(dropdown).click().build().perform();  //dropdown element is returning null 
}
```

TestClass

```
public class SecurityMainPageTests extends Basepage {

protected static SecurityMainPage sec = new SecurityMainPage(driver);
public SecurityMainPageTests(){}

@BeforeTest
public void setup(){
    OpenBrowser();
}
@Test
public void selectOptionTest(){
    sec.selectOption("Networking");
}
@AfterTest
public void tearDown(){
    closeBrowser();
}
```

**Log**

```
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-5J2KPMM3', ip: '192.168.0.36', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.convertUsingMethod(JsonOutput.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$13(JsonOutput.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$18(JsonOutput.java:152)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$19(JsonOutput.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$20(JsonOutput.java:161)
    at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.forEach(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$21(JsonOutput.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$SafeBiConsumer.accept(JsonOutput.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:248)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(JsonOutput.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(Json.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpCommandCodec.encode(AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:152)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:638)
    at test.java.SecurityMainPage.selectOption(SecurityMainPage.java:37)
    at test.java.SecurityMainPageTests.selectOptionTest(SecurityMainPageTests.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
    Suppressed: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Attempting to close incomplete json stream
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.close(JsonOutput.java:263)
        at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(Json.java:44)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.convertUsingMethod(JsonOutput.java:298)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getWrappedElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.PointerInput$Origin.asArg(PointerInput.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.PointerInput$Move.encode(PointerInput.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence.encode(Sequence.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Sequence.toJson(Sequence.java:84)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Please add the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: I think the issue is with `protected static SecurityMainPage sec = new SecurityMainPage(driver);`. You are passing a uninitiated parameter called `driver` to SecurityMainPage constructor.

Comment: @kaweesha I have added complete log details. Also, I run the test in debug mode and driver shows _null_ at the line you mentioned. Any pointers to overcome this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For easy understanding, I split the driver initiation and navigation to url to two methods in `Basepage`. And you haven't declared the `closeBrowser()` method.

Base Class

```
public class Basepage {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public Basepage(){}
 
    public Basepage(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }

    public WebDriver initiateDriver(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        "C:\\SeleniumWork\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    public void openBrowser(String url){
        driver.navigate().to(url);
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
public class SecurityMainPageTests extends Basepage {

    WebDriver driver = null;
    protected static SecurityMainPage sec = null;
    String url = "https://www.google.com";

    public SecurityMainPageTests(){}

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(){
        driver = initiateDriver();
        openBrowser(String url);
        sec = new SecurityMainPage(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void selectOptionTest(){
        sec.selectOption("Networking");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown(){
        closeBrowser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As per your suggestion, I moved the initialization of page object code inside _@BeforeTest_ and that fixed the test. Is there any way I can initialize page object outside the _@BeforeTest_?

Comment: You can use `@BeforeSuite` and write a method. Inside that method, you can initialize page objects. You don't need to initiate page objects outside the `@BeforeTest` in page factory model. Refer this [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I was able to initialise page objects outside _@BeforeTest_ or _@BeforeSuite_ in C# page object pattern. However, I was trying to achieve same in Java. Looks like I must initialise them inside a methods annotated with either suite or test.